# while loop not showing anything

Tags: php, while-loop

I'm trying to get my page to show all the news that I have in my database. 
But on my website nothing is showing there is no errors to let me know if anything is wrong, there is just a blank page.
I have used var_dump() and it returns all the data that I requested.

Here is my code for the page

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
header("Content-type: text/xml");
include("includes/database.php");
global $NEWS;
$str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
$str.= '<rss version="2.0">';
$str.='<channel>';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ($sql."".mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
    $str.= '<item>';
    $str.= '<title>'.$row->title.'</title>';
    $str.= '<description>'.$row->content. '</description>';
    $str.= '</item>';
}

$str .='</channel>';
$str .='</rss>';
echo $str;
```

Comment: Anything in the source of the page?

Comment: Did you open the database and invoke the `mysql_select_db` function to select the database.

Comment: yep all the information is in the source of the page.

Comment: I did invoke the mysql_select_db. I did that in my database.php which I included in my page where the loop is.

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_` functions. They are deprecated. Instead, use `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 3):

```
   <?php
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  header("Content-type: text/xml"); 
include("includes/database.php");
global $NEWS;
$str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
$str.= '<rss version="2.0">';
$str.='<channel>';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ($sql."".mysql_error());

foreach($row in mysql_fetch_object($result)){
    $str.= '<item>';
    $str.= '<title>'.$row->title.'</title>';
    $str.= '<description>'.$row->content. '</description>';
    $str.= '</item>';
}

$str .='</channel>';
$str .='</rss>';
echo $str;
```

Comment: but the above while loop u used was not correct..
there must be some other error

are u getting any error

Comment: I'm not getting any errors at all. I have display_errors on, but nothing has shown up

Answer (score 0):

check database connection:

```
mysql_connect("hostname", "user", "password");
mysql_select_db("mydb");
```